# NaN or 0 shows up in sum up

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the process of summing up input values, overall is always showed up `NaN` or `O` ( sum up function below). I can't sum values up. All values are Number and their variable also `Number` according to the console information. Everywhere I use `parseInt` and `Number` methods.
The sum up function is also used with `parseInt` method. I had to add the logical operator `||` in the sum up function, after that, it always showed up `0`.

```js
 // points declaration for  rate determenation
     $(function () {
      $("#name_vehicle").change(function () { 

       var vehicle_value = $(this).val(),
        vehicle_point = $("#vehicle_point").val();

         vehicle_point = ( vehicle_value == "1" ) ? 1 :
                        ( vehicle_value == "2" ) ? 1 : 
                              ( vehicle_value == "3" ) ? 1 : 
                                     ( vehicle_value == "4" ) ? 1 : 
                                            ( vehicle_value == "5" ) ? 1: 
                                                (vehicle_value == "6" ) ? 2 : 0;


          $("#vehicle_point").val( vehicle_point );
     console.log ( vehicle_point );
        
      });// end change
                   
     }); // end ready
     
      $(function () {

        $("#term").change(function () { 

         var tv = $(this).val();
           var tp = $("#term_point").val();

          tp = ( tv == "1") ? 24:
                ( tv == "2") ? 36 :
                  ( tv == "3") ? 48:
                    ( tv == "4") ? 60 : 0;

              $("#term_point").val( tp );
              console.log ( tp );
                                                          
             }); // end change
                            
       }); // end ready
       
       
       $(function () {
             $("input").change(function () { 

          var cp = parseInt($("input[name=carPrice").val());
           var d = parseInt($("input[name=deposit").val());
           var ae = parseInt($("input[name=add_equip").val());
             var c = parseInt ($("input[name=casco]").val());
               var tp = parseInt($("input[name=term_point").val());

             var result = ( ( cp + ae ) - d + c );
              var pd =  ((d / ( cp + ae )) * 100); // DEPOSIT IN %

              $("#overall").val( result );
                                console.log ( result );

             $("#p_deposit").val( pd );
                                console.log ( pd );
                                console.log ( typeof pd );
                                  

        var cl_points = parseInt($("input[name=cl_points").val());
          var bl_points = parseInt($("input[name=bl_points").val());

                                if ( pd >= 20 && pd < 39.99 ) {
                                    cl_points =  1;
                                    bl_points =  1;
                                }
                                else if ( pd > 39.99 && pd < 49.99) {
                                    cl_points =  1;
                                    bl_points =  5;
                                }
                                else if ( pd > 49.99 && pd <= 55 ) {
                                    cl_points =  1;
                                    bl_points =  5;
                                }
                                else if ( pd > 55 && pd < 99.99 ) {
                                    cl_points =  1;
                                    bl_points =  0; 
                                }

                                $("#cl_points").val( cl_points );
                                $("#bl_points").val( bl_points );

                                console.log ( cl_points );
                                console.log ( bl_points );
                               
                            }); // end change
                            
                        }); // end ready
               
             $(function () {

            var sum = 0;

              $(".points").each(function () {

                   sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;

                      $("#overallPoints").val( sum ) ;       
                                    console.log (sum);
                                    console.log ( typeof sum);
                                    
                                }); // end each
                                
                            }); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- first header-->
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <!-- box one-->

      <i class="fa fa-car" id="v1" style="font-size:84px;color:white"><span class="w1">А</span></i>

      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="l1" for="name_vehicle">В</label>
          <select multiple class="form-control" id="name_vehicle">
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">T</option>
            <option value="3">Q</option>
            <option value="4">X</option>
            <option value="5">M</option>
            <option value="6">J</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" class="points" id="vehicle_point" style="display:none">
          <!-- POINT ONE-->
        </div>
      </form>

      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="l1" for="carPrice">С:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="carPrice" name="carPrice" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="l1" for="add_equip">о:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_equip" name="add_equip" value="0">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <!-- box two-->

      <i class="fa fa-money" style="font-size:84px;color:white"><span class="w1">К</span></i>

      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="l1" for="deposit">П</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deposit" name="deposit" value="0">
          <input type="text" id="car_loan" style="display:none" name="car_loan">
          <!-- CAR LOAN SUM-->
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="l1" for="term">С</label>
          <select multiple class="form-control" id="term">
            <option value="1">24 </option>
            <option value="2">36 </option>
            <option value="3">48 </option>
            <option value="4">60 </option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" class="points" id="term_point" style="display:none" name="term_point">
          <!-- POINT TWO-->

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="l1" for="casco">К:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casco" name="casco" value="0">
          <input type="text" id="overall" style="display:none" name="overall">
          <!--SUM UP-->
          <input type="text" id="p_deposit" style="display:none">
          <!-- DEPOSIT IN %-->
          <input type="text" class="points" id="p_deposit_point" style="display:none" name="p_deposit_point">
          <!-- POINT THREE-->

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: guess you really want to make sure that 1 and 0 are numbers. Not sure why you are using Number() for things that are numbers. It is not needed.

Comment: Just change it to `(vehicle_value == "1") ? vehicle_point = 1 : 0;` for all your numbers

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and use that to simplify your sample code.

Comment: Your assignments are strange and probably wrong. Put the variable to assign at the front. Also leave out Number() because you already have numbers. Result: `vehicle_point = (vehicle_value == "1") ?  1: 0;`

Comment: Also to add - your inputs are `type="text"` - if you are using numbers you could change them to `type="number"`

Comment: I removed all `Number` methods. Still can't sum up ( code has been changed above)

Comment: Maybe you should indent your code properly. Some of your function body code is even less indented than the function keyword. Horrible.

Comment: @trincot, thank you for your advice. But i have already figured it out by pasting part of the code in the `$("input").change(function () { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when you have a number, you do not have to use Number() to ensure it is a number.

The logic here is wrong:

```
(tv == "1") ? tp = Number(24): Number(0);
(tv == "2") ? tp = Number(36): Number(0);
(tv == "3") ? tp = Number(48): Number(0);
(tv == "4") ? tp = Number(60): Number(0);
```

You can not use a ternary operator here for this. When you say tv=2, first one will set it to zero, second would set it to 36, third will set it back to 0.

A ternary operator would have to look like:

```
(tv == "1") ? tp = Number(24): 
  (tv == "2") ? tp = Number(36):
    (tv == "3") ? tp = Number(48): 
      (tv == "4") ? tp = Number(60): Number(0);
```

But that really makes little sense to do.

You would be better off to use a switch statement of if/else if

```
switch (tv) {
  case "1": tp = 24; break;
  case "2": tp = 36; break;
  case "3": tp = 48; break;
  case "4": tp = 60; break;
  case default: tp = 0; break;
}
```

Same thing applies with vehicle point.

Comment: I deleted all `Number` methods. Used a ternary operator as you advised. Finally, the condition stayed the same. No changes, it can't still sum up ( code changed above)

Comment: or just `tp = ["1", "2", "3", "4"].includes(tv) ? (12 + parseInt (tv) * 12) : 0;`